# How can i execute a list of methods on an object in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, object, logic

I have a list of methods which I have to execute on an Object.
These are the methods

```
methods = ['plays', 'plays', 'is', 'is']
relation_dict = {}
```

I want to get a relation dictionary which looks like this

```
relation_dict = {'plays':FOAF.plays,'plays':FOAF.plays, 'is':FOAF.is, 'is':FOAF.is}
```

here `FOAF` is the object. How can we do this?

Comment: Yes you are right it is an XY problem now that you mentioned it became clear that i can't do the problem like this.

Comment: @j1-lee I want to associate the strings in the list to FOAF.string_name so that it will perform that FOAF thing on my string_name

Answer (score 1):

you could achive something similar like this :

```
obj = FOAF
for i in methods: 
   getattr(obj, i)() # <-- this will call the needed method
```

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an oneliner way:

```
methods = ['plays', 'plays', 'is', 'is']
relation_dict = {method: getattr(FOAF, method) for method in methods}
```